# Bash: extract column using empty lines as separators

Tags: bash

I have a file like:

```
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  

a  
b  
c  
d  
e
```

And want to put it like:

```
1 a  
2 b  
3 c  
4 d  
5 e
```

Is there a quick way to do it in bash?

Comment: tried anything?

Comment: copy in libreoffice calc to separate columns and copy back to file....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pr` is the tool to use for columnizing data:

```
pr -s" " -T -2 filename
```

Comment: Note that this assume the GNU implementation of `pr`.

Answer (score 1):

With `paste` and process substitution:

```
$ paste -d " " <(sed -n '1,/^$/{/^$/d;p}' file) <(sed -n '/^$/,${//!p}' file)
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple bash script the does the job:

```
nums=()
is_line=0
cat ${1} | while read line
do
    if [[ ${line} == '' ]]
    then
        is_line=1
    else
        if [[ ${is_line} == 0 ]]
        then
            nums=("${nums[@]}" "${line}")
        else
            echo ${nums[0]} ${line}
            nums=(${nums[*]:1})
        fi
    fi
done
```

Run it like this: `./script filename`

Example:

```
$ ./script filein
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ rs 2 5 <file | rs -T
1  a
2  b
3  c
4  d
5  e
```

If you want that extra separator space off, use `-g1` in the latter `rs`. Explained:

- print `file` in 5 cols and 2 rows
- `-T` transpose it